# Error message when installing new tomcat server (5.5) 

Tags: java, exception, tomcat, jstl

I have installed a new tomcat server (5.5) and I get this exception:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:  Unable to load tag handler class "org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.WhenTag" for tag "c:when"

I guess I am missing the JSTL but I can't find how do add it to the tomcat server.

i found jstl-api-1.2.jar and jstl-impl-1.2.jar [here](http://jstl.java.net/)
i have put them in the WEB-INF/lib
and now i get this exception

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>   An error occurred at line: 29 in the jsp file: /jsp/general/pos/DoMultiWordFrozen.jspf
>   Type mismatch: cannot convert from Boolean to boolean

the same code was working on my old (tomcat 5.5.12) server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@yossi, yes you are missing **JSTL taglib**.
download **JSTL 1.1/jstl.jar** and **standard.jar** to `WEB-INF/lib` Folder.
If you are using **Maven** in your project you can add below dependency to your *pom.xml*

```
  <!-- standard.jar --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can find out more *Maven releases* [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard)

Comment: where can i find jstl.jar ? i only found jstl-impl-1.2.jar and as i understand it only good for tomcat 6 and up

Comment: @yossi you can find jar files from [archive_apache_standard](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/taglibs/standard-1.0/binaries/) or [java2s_download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjstl11jar.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can add **jstl.jar** into web application, just copy **jstl.jar** to **WEB-INF/lib**.